# How do I set an environment variable in a linux makefile

Tags: linux, bash, makefile

I have the following makefile (snippet)

```
INSTALL_LIB = /usr/local/lib

...

install:
  @echo libs are at $(INSTALL_LIB)
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(INSTALL_LIB)
  @echo libs will be installed at $(LD_LIBRARY_PATH)
```

However, `make install` will result in:

```
lib path is /usr/local/lib
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
libs will be installed at
```

same result is gotten by

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(INSTALL_LIB)
```

or

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$(INSTALL_LIB)"
```

I am certain I am missing something fundamental about how make works, but scouring the web has not yielded anything concrete.

What's confusing me even more is that

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH= $(INSTALL_LIB)
```

results in

```
/bin/sh: /usr/local/lib: is a directory
```

and

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH = $(INSTALL_LIB)
```

results in

```
/bin/sh: LD_LIBRARY_PATH: command not found
```

**--------------edit-----------------**

By suggestion, I changed the makefile to:

```
INSTALL_LIB = /usr/local/lib

...

install:
  @echo libs are at $(INSTALL_LIB)
  @LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(INSTALL_LIB);\
  echo libs will be installed at $$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

and the output becomes as expected:

```
lib path is /usr/local/lib
libs will be installed at /usr/local/lib
```

This solves this problem. (However, I am still wondering how to make `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` available outside of the makefile instance, on the command line for example)

Comment: I have searched the web and SO, but I found nothing that directly pertained to my question. I would be greatly thankful if someone could point out which question this is a duplicate of (instead of just flagging it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each *line* of a recipe is executed in a separate shell, so the line

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(INSTALL_LIB)
```

is only in effect for the shell in which it runs. You'll either have to set the value of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in the shell command which needs it, but you'll need to show more of you `Makefile` for advice on how to do that.

Comment: `Each line of a recipe is executed in a separate shell` This helped a lot, and in answered this question. However, as a follow up: how do I make available `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` outside of the makefile? I tried `export` to no avail.

Comment: You cannot. Children inherit their environment from their parent, but you cannot otherwise modify the environment of another process.

Comment: `You cannot.` Alas. Thanks, I will resort to piping the value to a file then.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by _outside of the makefile_.  You can change an environment variable in the current process, and any child process that is invoked by that process will inherit that value.  In this case `make` is the process, and the makefile can change environment variables in the `make` process, and any child processes `make` invokes (e.g., recipes `make` runs) can inherit that value.  If what you want is for the `make` program to change the environment of the caller of `make`, then as @chepner says that's not possible: this is an operating system restriction, not `make`.